# Relevel does not change the results of my regression despite changing the reference group

Tags: r, regression

I would like to do regression to find relationship between ln_wage and education level.
The education levels are used as dummy variables. The data looks like this:

```
unique(data1$grade)
```

> 'MiddleSchool' 'University' 'Primary' 'Vocational' 'HighSchool' 'PostSecondary'

AT first, the reference group is HighSchool as I checked with `contrast()` , it returns:

```
data1$grade = as.factor(data1$grade)
contrasts(data1$grade)

                  MiddleSchool  PostSecondary   Primary University  Vocational
HighSchool             0              0             0        0           0
MiddleSchool           1              0             0        0           0
PostSecondary          0              1             0        0           0
Primary                0              0             1        0           0
University             0              0             0        1           0
Vocational             0              0             0        0           1
```

Then, I proceed to do regression.

```
olsreg <- lm(ln_wage ~ age + age_sqr + grade + indus + year -1, data=data1)
summary(olsreg)$coefficient
                      Estimate   Std. Error
> gradePrimary          2.561   1.127378e-02
> gradeMiddleSchool     2.680   1.108296e-02
> gradeHighSchool       2.743   1.128950e-02
> gradeVocational       2.820   1.165518e-02
> gradePostSecondary    2.915   1.147913e-02
> gradeUniversity       3.191   1.136915e-02
```

The results show every category, not one is omitted as the reference group.

Then, I proceed to use `relevel` to change the reference group to Primary.

```
data1$grade = relevel(data1$grade, ref='Primary')
contrasts(data1$grade)
                  HighSchool    MiddleSchool  PostSecondary  University Vocational
Primary               0             0               0             0          0
HighSchool            1             0               0             0          0
MiddleSchool          0             1               0             0          0
PostSecondary         0             0               1             0          0
University            0             0               0             1          0
Vocational            0             0               0             0          1
```

The reference group changed to Primary.
Then, I do regression again.

```
olsreg <- lm(ln_wage ~ age + age_sqr + grade + indus + year -1, data=data1)
summary(olsreg)$coefficient
                      Estimate   Std. Error
> gradePrimary          2.561   1.127378e-02
> gradeMiddleSchool     2.680   1.108296e-02
> gradeHighSchool       2.743   1.128950e-02
> gradeVocational       2.820   1.165518e-02
> gradePostSecondary    2.915   1.147913e-02
> gradeUniversity       3.191   1.136915e-02
```

The coefficients do not change at all from the previous regression, and there also seems to be no baseline.
What did I do wrong here? Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: This happens because you have removed the intercept. The base level is now what used to be the intercept (the mean of the reference level) and the other coefficients are no longer differences to that level, they are total values (once again, mean values) of the effect sizes of each level. And this doesn't change with changes in the reference level. Without intercept all coef values are mean effect sizes. Sorry if I'm using *"total"* and *"mean"* somewhat interchangeably. Here *"total"* opposes *"difference to the other levels"*.